# Restricting user scopes by using an on-behalf-of flow with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a SPA React application which use MSAL for logging users in and acquiring tokens for querying MS Graph. Currently, when the user is created he/she can have two different roles, namely:

- Administrator
- Viewer

As is, every user is allowed to get the same scopes from AAD - Regardless of whether they are one or the other role.

This presents a problem - Because any of the users potentially have the same permissions when calling MS Graph, i.e. they could acquire the token themselves and request graph with full scopes.

The viewer role should only be able to have the `[User.Read]` scope, while the administrator should be able to alter every aspect of Azure AD.

Additionally, the administrator should be able to perform actions in MS graph that isn't supported by delegated permissions, i.e. [creating new users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The following makes me think that I may need to rethink the way that users are requesting resources from MS graph - which lead me to thinking that the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) would be an interesting option.

As I imagine, the flow would work as follows (from when a user logs in, and requests to create a new user in my SPA)

1. User logs in with MSAL in my SPA
2. User gets the least privileged scope, i.e. `[user.Read]`
3. User creates a new user
4. SPA sends a request to my Web API with the users' token as bearer
5. Web API validates the user token with AAD
6. Web API validates that the user has a role of "Administrator"
7. Web API gets a token with `["User.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"]` scopes
8. Web API calls graph with the fetched application scopes on behalf of the user
9. Web API returns the data to my SPA

Since I'm fairly new to this world - I'm wondering if my way of thinking makes sense. In particular, I'm curious if it's really possible to request elevated permissions `["User.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"]` on behalf of a user with only the `[user.Read]` scope from my Web API.

Additionally, I'm of cause open for any suggestions for alternative ways to solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scopes (delegated permissions) apply to an application, not a user.
Fundamentally, no matter what scopes the user gets in their token, they cannot do anything they were not already able to do.
Microsoft Graph API checks the scopes to check the application's permissions, and then checks the user's permissions to see if they are also able to do the operation.
Thus a user can never elevate their permissions through scopes.

If you have any of your own APIs, you should also handle authorization in a similar way.
If scopes are used, also check the user's permissions.
In case of application permissions (app roles with member type application), there isn't a user so your API would only check these permissions.
This is why you need to be extra careful with authorization if your back-end uses application permissions instead of on-behalf-of flow; since they don't include the user, it could allow them to elevate their privileges through your application.